# What's NOT in an interface file?

Tags: compilation, d, header-files

I was under the impression that ["A D interface file contains only what an import of the module needs, rather than the whole implementation of that module."](http://www.d-programming-language.org/dmd-windows.html#interface_files)  To me, that translates to signatures - just return types, names and arguments, so that the compiler knows it's valid and the linker can do the dirty work later.

Running a file through `dmd`, though, strips almost nothing:

```
import std.stdio;

void SayHello(const string Name)
{
    writeln("Hello, ", Name, "!");
}
```

```
dmd Interface.d -o- -H
```

```
// D import file generated from 'Interface.d'
import std.stdio;
void SayHello(const string Name)
{
writeln("Hello, ",Name,"!");
}
```

Hardly a paragon of optimization.

What, exactly, is stripped in interface files?

([header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files) added because it's the closest thing I could find.)

Comment: I've often wondered what it would take to make the .di files a binary format with a serialized copy of the source with most of the work already done: mmap it in, insert a pointer to it into the correct symbol table, done.

Comment: @BCS `.di` files aren't actually part of the standard, so there aren't any politics to get in the way of that idea.  I wonder why they haven't done it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any function which is going to be inlined must have its full source in the .di file. Any function which is going to be used in CTFE must not only have its full source in the .di file, but the full source of every function that it uses - directly or indirectly - must be available to the compiler. Also, because of how templates work, their full source must be in the .di file as well (which is the same as how templates must be in header files in C++). So, there are a number of cases where you *need* stuff to be in a .di file.

Under exactly what circumstances the compiler chooses to strip stuff or not, I don't know (aside from the fact that templates automatically end up in .di files in their entirety because they *have* to). It could change depending on the compiler's current implementation and what optimizations it does. But at minimum, it's going to have to leave in small function bodies if it's going to do any inlining. Large function bodies and the bodies of small virtual functions (which can't be inlined anyway) will likely be stripped out however. But your example gives a small, non-virtual function, so dmd likely left it in so that it could inline any calls to it. If you want to see dmd strip a lot of stuff when generating a .di file, then you probably need to have large functions and/or use classes.

Answer (score 4):

> Hardly a paragon of optimization.

No, that **is** an optimization. The compiler will leave the implementation in the interface file if the implementation is small enough that it can later be inlined.